# Access web service::schema issue

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

I have Spring Web Service based on [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) example. That configured in this way

```
@Endpoint
public class HolidayEndpoint {

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "HolidayRequest")
public void  handleHolidayRequest(@RequestPayload Element holidayRequest) throws Exception {...}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring config

```
    <sws:annotation-driven/>

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="holiday" portTypeName="HumanResource" locationUri="/holidayService/"
                      targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/somexsd.xsd"/>
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

How I should access it?

I've tried to post at `http://localhost:8080/ws/holidayService/holiday` but server returned `404` and wrote in log

at starting

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Looking for endpoints in application context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-ws-servlet': startup date [Fri Mar 11 18:41:42 EET 2011]; root of context hierarchy
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Mapped [{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}HolidayRequest] onto endpoint [public void com.mycompany.hr.ws.HolidayEndpoint.handleHolidayRequest(org.jdom.Element) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Looking for endpoints in application context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-ws-servlet': startup date [Fri Mar 11 18:41:42 EET 2011]; root of context hierarchy
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider] - Inlining SimpleXsdSchema{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.DefaultMessagesProvider] - Looking for elements in schema with target namespace [http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.DefaultMessagesProvider] - Creating message [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HolidayRequest]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider] - Creating port type [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HumanResource]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider] - Adding operation [Holiday] to port type [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HumanResource]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.Soap11Provider] - Creating binding [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HumanResourceSoap11]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.Soap11Provider] - Creating service [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HumanResourceService]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.Soap11Provider] - Adding port [HumanResourceSoap11] to service [{http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions}HumanResourceService]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'spring-ws' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring-ws]
INFO [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] - Using MessageFactory class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - No WebServiceMessageFactory found in servlet 'spring-ws': using default
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - No EndpointExceptionResolvers found, using defaults
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - No MessageDispatcher found in servlet 'spring-ws': using default
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - Published [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition@6fc41e49] as holiday.wsdl
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - Published [SimpleXsdSchema{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}] as org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema#0.xsd
```

per  request

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter] - Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@3bd85e85] at [http://localhost:8080/ws/holidayService/holiday]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received] - Received request [SaajSoapMessage HolidayRequest]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Looking up endpoint for [HolidayRequest]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@2081ca25] has no mapping for request
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Looking up endpoint for []
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@3ad8326d] has no mapping for request
WARN [org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound] - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage HolidayRequest]
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
```

If you need some additional info let me know, please.

**UPD** It worked without scheme/namespace stuff.

Comment: I've access it from same domain javascript code. I can post it, if it metters.

Comment: Have you turned-on debugging?  When I worked with Spring WS in the past it was almost impossible to debug these kind of problems without that.  After you get that info please attach that.

Comment: @SOA Nerd, real log provided.

Comment: I suppose that there is problems with namespacees. Any other suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you http://localhost:8080/ws/holidayService/ instead of /HumanService/